# Making slider not exceed height of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I'm using bxslider (can use any free slider if needed) and I want to make it not exceed the viewport height. For example, the slider works fine on iPhone/Nexus 5 (portrait), but when in landscape, the photos have bigger height and you have to scroll to see them. This is because I have content above the slider, if I were to delete it, it would be 100% height and would work fine.

The site you can see it on - http://laurakok.openyourpage.com/ (note - you have to be on touch device, or use emulation (chrome for example)).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Slick.

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick

You can set settings at different breakpoints.

Comment: Well, I've played with it all day and I think it's not exactly what I need. I need something like this http://horizon.4ormat.com/ (try it on touch devices (emulation)), it always fits on screen.